# Page counter doesn't work in equation on top of a new page

Tags: equations, numbering, align, counters, zref

In the example below (sorry, I don't know how to make it smaller), I try to include the page number in the equation numbering, but on top of a new page, the equation gets numbered by the previous page not by the page it is actually on. I indicate where the problem occurs with a sentence that references the incorrectly numbered equation. As you can see, on top of page 3, all 4 equations in the `align` environment get numbered by the previous page.

I see the same problem with any theorem-like environment.

Motivation: it is much easier to find an equation (or any theoremlike structure) in a large article or book if the reference indicates the page number instead of the section or anything else.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}
\numberwithin{equation}{page}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:1}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:2}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:3}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:4}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:5}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:6}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:7}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:8}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:9}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:10}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:11}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:12}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:13}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:14}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:15}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:16}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:17}  
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{eq:17} is on page \pageref{eq:17}, not on the
previous page.
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:18}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:19}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:20}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:21}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:22}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:23}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:24}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:25}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:26}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:27}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:28}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:29}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:30}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:31}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:32}  
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  \frac12&=\frac24\label{eq:33} \\
  \frac12&=\frac24\\
  \frac12&=\frac24\\
  \frac12&=\frac24
\end{align}
Equation \eqref{eq:33} is on page \pageref{eq:33}, not on the previous
page.
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:34}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:35}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:36}  
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

Added (thanks!!!): The `perpage` package worked perfectly. One remark: it requires an extra run of latex.  I could even use it for theoremlike environments.  Here is what I needed to do to have all theorems be numbered by page.  Note that the counter redefinition had to be done after the definition of the `thm` environment since the counter `thm` counter doesn't exist before.

```
\mdtheorem[style=theorem]{thm}{Theorem}
\let\origthethm\thethm
\MakePerPage{thm}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\theperpage.\origthethm}
```

Comment: The page counter is increased at shipout of the page, i.e. at the end, not at the beginning of a page

Comment: I hope the `\label{eq:1}` system is only used to track the equations here in demonstration, not in your real document

Comment: you can never refer to the page counter in the body of the document as page breaking happens later after all macros have been expanded, you always need to refer to it indirectly eg via `\pageref`

Comment: Basically any real setup of a sophisticated document with LateX requires two or more runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `perpage` package, which is designed for such `per - page` activities. The correct page value can be retrieved with the `\theperpage` macro.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{amsart}

\let\origtheequation\theequation

\usepackage{perpage}

\MakePerPage{equation}


\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theperpage.\origtheequation}



\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:1}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:2}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:3}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:4}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:5}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:6}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:7}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:8}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:9}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:10}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:11}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:12}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:13}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:14}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:15}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:16}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:17}  
\end{equation}
Equation \eqref{eq:17} is on page \pageref{eq:17}, not on the
previous page.
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:18}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:19}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:20}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:21}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:22}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:23}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:24}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:25}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:26}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:27}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:28}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:29}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:30}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:31}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:32}  
\end{equation}
\begin{align}
  \frac12&=\frac24\label{eq:33} \\
  \frac12&=\frac24\\
  \frac12&=\frac24\\
  \frac12&=\frac24
\end{align}
Equation \eqref{eq:33} is on page \pageref{eq:33}, not on the previous
page.
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:34}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:35}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:36}  
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: example would be more compelling if the visual showed two pages, with the xref on the first page to an equation on the second.  (the code *is* solid, but if someone just looks at the present visual, it looks "manufactured".)  maybe use `geometry` to set a shorter page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `zref` package, in particular its `perpage` module.

Note the usage of `\thezpage` for getting the correct page number, which is not the same as `\thepage` in some circumstances: the problem is that TeX typesets things further before realizing it has to eject a page; this is done in order to find the optimal page break point according to its rules.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\usepackage{zref-perpage}

\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry} % just for the example

\zmakeperpage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thezpage.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:1}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:2}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:3}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:4}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:5}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:6}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:7}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:8}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:9}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:10}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:11}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:12}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:13}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:14}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:15}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:16}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:17}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:18}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:19}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:20}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:21}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:22}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:23}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:24}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:25}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:26}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:27}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:28}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:29}  
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \frac12=\frac24\label{eq:30}  
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The `geometry` package has been used just for reducing the amount of code and for showing several pages in a small picture.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @egreg, this works, but in theorem environment, the problem persists. See   [http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/350260/](zref-perpage doesn't work with theorem-like environments)