# zref-perpage doesn't work with theorem-like environments

Tags: equations, theorems, zref

I am trying to use the `zref-perpage` package to number theorem-like enviroments and equations by page.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work well.  In this first example, we see that the second `thm` appears on the 2nd page, but its counter is 1.2 instead of 2.1.  The equation numbers come out OK.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[textheight=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{zref-perpage}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\zmakeperpage{thm}

\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thezpage.\arabic{thm}}
\zmakeperpage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thezpage.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
  \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

In the second example, the only change I make is I increase the `textheight` from 1 in to 1.5 in.  This makes the second `thm` begin on the first page but finishes on the second page.  As you can see, this time the equation counter gets messed up: the second equation is on the 2nd page, but it gets the label 1.3, so as if it was on page 1.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[textheight=1.5in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{zref-perpage}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\zmakeperpage{thm}

\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thezpage.\arabic{thm}}
\zmakeperpage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thezpage.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
  \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

At the suggestion of @christian, in the following example I only use `article` and, with `textheight=.9in`, the second `thm` is on the 2nd page, but the `thm` counter shows 1.2 instead of 2.1.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
%\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage[textheight=.9in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{zref-perpage}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\zmakeperpage{thm}

\renewcommand{\thethm}{\thezpage.\arabic{thm}}
\zmakeperpage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thezpage.\arabic{equation}}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
  \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

This example shows that the `perpage` package doesn't work either.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[textheight=.9in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{perpage}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
\let\origthethm\thethm
\MakePerPage{thm}
\renewcommand{\thethm}{\theperpage.\origthethm}

\let\origtheequation\theequation
\MakePerPage{equation}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theperpage.\origtheequation}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}

\begin{thm}
  We have
  \begin{equation}
    \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}

  \begin{equation}
  \int_1^e\frac1x = 1
  \end{equation}
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: likely related: [Page counter doesn't work in equation on top of a new page](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/349675/579)

Comment: Using the `perpage` package works (as in the question linked by @barbarabeeton). I don't think this is related to the `thm` environment at all

Comment: @christian and @barbarabeeton : Thanks guys a lot.  My problem is that, in fact, I am also using the `mdframed` package and `perpage` has a conflict with it. I think the reason for the conflict is that `mdframed` loads the `zref-abspage` package. I would show here an example, but I do not know how to do this in this comment box. What can I do? No doubt, I have to abandon `zref` since it has other problems: it resets the equation numbers when the `align` environment is used.

Comment: @christian , @barbara : it doesn't work even if I just use `article`. I'll show in a minute in the original post.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer , @BarbaraBeeton : I added the fourth example which shows that `perpage` doesn't work either: the second `thm` gets 1.2 though it's on the second page.  The equations are fine.  I am now using only `article`.

Comment: I still think that numbering equation per page is not a good idea; for theorems it's even worse.

Comment: @MátéWierdl: I was using a different version with an explicit clearpage. I'll remove my comment about `article`

Comment: @egreg : In a typical book, if equations are numbered by, say, chapters, it takes a long time to find, say, equation (3.17) since chapter 3 may have 100 pages.  The same with theorems.  On the other hand, if I equations are numbered by page and I see (38.17), I know that I just need to go to page 38.  When you have to look up a bunch of equations simultaneously, as in a multiple reference, the pain is close to unbearable.   So I really don't know what the advantage of numbering by sections could be. Perhaps aesthetics because of the smaller numbers.

Comment: Perhaps I make one more remark: I think we have a similar practical problem with the usual recommendation of using the plain bibliography style and having all the references collected at the end of a paper.  If I see [55] in a paper, I need to go to the end of the article to see what the cited  reference is and if I see [55] later, I have to repeat.  Painful. References in footnotes are not so great, I agree, but the tufte styles provide an imo excellent solution: they leave more right margin than usual, and references could appear, of course, at the end of the book or paper, too.

Answer (score 1):

Environment `equation`, redefined by package `amsmath`, increments the equation counter *before* the math is started. Thus, it happens that there is a page break between the counter setting and the displayed math equation. The former is the place, where the label is set to get the page number.

Workarounds:

- Putting a `minipage` around to prevent the page break:

  ```
  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
    \begin{equation}...\end{equation}
  \end{minipage}
  ```
- Redefinition of `\equation` to move `\incr@eqnum`, which calls `\refstepcounter{equation}`, to a later place:

  ```
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand*{\equation}{% amsmath version
    \nobreak
    \mathdisplay@push
    \st@rredfalse
    \global\@eqnswtrue
    \mathdisplay{equation}%
    \incr@eqnum
  } 
  \makeatother
  ```

Comment: Thank you.  I do not understand.  The problem is not with the equation counter but the `thm` counter.  So in the first workaround, didn't you mean to put a `minipage` around `thm` instead of `equation`?  

My last example uses only `article`, so I guess that doesn't have `amsmath` version of `equation`.

Comment: Putting a minipage around `thm` did help, thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if a `thm` could run onto the next page---especially since a minipage may put my `thm` on top of the page number (as it happens in my actual document a number of times).   Isn't there some kind of trick you did with `equation` to use for `thm` ?

Comment: @MátéWierdl There is no simple trick. Each implementation of a theorem (there are lots of theorem packages) needs to be investigated, where the counter is incremented and if there is a reliable way to move it to a better place if necessary.